# Validation constraints importFrom throws exception

Tags: grails, grails3, grails3.2.0

I'm getting following exepction when trying to import constraints from domain class which uses shared constraint.
Exception occurs during binding phase

Exception:

```
Property [somePackage.User.email] references shared constraint [email:null], which doesn't exist!
```

Domain:

```
class User {
    String email
    static constraints = {
        email(shared: 'email', unique: true)
}
```

Command

```
class UpdateClientCommand {
    String email

    static constraints = {
        importFrom User
    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Property [clearhub.User.email] references shared constraint [email:null], which doesn't exist!. Stacktrace follows:


 Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Property [mypackage.User.email] references shared constraint [email:null], which doesn't exist!
        at org.grails.validation.DefaultConstraintEvaluator.applySharedConstraints(DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java:287)
        at org.grails.validation.DefaultConstraintEvaluator.evaluateConstraintsMap(DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java:245)
        at org.grails.validation.DefaultConstraintEvaluator.evaluateConstraints(DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java:132)
        at org.grails.validation.DefaultConstraintEvaluator.evaluateConstraints(DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java:119)
        at org.grails.validation.DefaultConstraintEvaluator.evaluate(DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java:80)
        at org.grails.validation.ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.handleImportFrom(ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.java:173)
        at org.grails.validation.ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.createNode(ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.java:165)
        at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:101)
        at org.grails.validation.ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(ConstrainedPropertyBuilder.java:72)
        at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:67)
        at mypackage.UpdateClientCommand$__clinit__closure1.doCall(ClientController.groovy:47)
        at org.grails.validation.DefaultConstraintEvaluator.evaluateConstraintsMap(DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java:240)
        at org.grails.validation.DefaultConstraintEvaluator.evaluateConstraints(DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java:144)
        at org.grails.validation.DefaultConstraintEvaluator.evaluate(DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java:92)
        at grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.validate(Validateable.groovy:149)
        at grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.validate(Validateable.groovy:82)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: After some debugging it seems like such scenario is not supported. I dropped using shared constraints in favor of 'importFrom'

Comment: If there are other fields you can still you use importFrom and exclude that specific field that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a constraint as *shared* - it should be defined in *grails.gorm.default.constraints* of *grails-app/conf/Config.groovy*. Let me guess that 'email' is not defined there so you get this exception?

Just remove the "shared: 'email'," from User and import will should work fine.

Useful link: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.by/2014/03/grails-goodness-combining-constraints.html